# Как быть с большим объемом данных?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Имеется файл примерно на 700 000 записей, мне необходимо периодически его проверять, если есть изменения то делаю update в базу,если нет то записываю в базу. Нужно как то ускорить этот процесс. и я не понимаю как сохранять это дело в моем случаи. уперся вот на этом моменте.
не судите строго я новичок. Надеюсь код лучше объяснит.

```
  DB::table('resources')->select('hash')->orderBy('id')->chunk(50000,
            function ($resources) use ($file, $updatedDate) {

                $lineCount = 1;
                echo 1 . '<>';
                while (!feof($file)) {


                    $line = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', fgets($file));
                    $csv = str_getcsv($line, ';');
                    if (count($csv) === 6) {
                        $ipPool = explode('|', $csv[0]);
                        foreach ($ipPool as $ip) {
                            $date = new \DateTime($csv[5]);
                            $hash = md5($csv[1] . $csv[2]);

                            foreach ($resources as $resource) {
                                if ($hash === $resource->hash) {
                                    DB::table('resources')->where('hash', $hash)->update([
                                        'version_date' => $updatedDate,
                                    ]);
                                    echo $lineCount++ . "<br>"  ;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $lineCount++;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если весь вопрос в том что страница зависает на 1 минуту, можно сделать это асинхронно через очереди.
Либо используй две таблицы в базе данных, грузи туда целиком файл, в одной таблице предыдущая версия в другой текущая, и проверяй запросом. В итоге будет меньше запросов, и все вычисления на уровне БД, должен быть приличный прирост.